# Calling -init multiple times in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What happens when you call -init multiple times on one object, are there some hidden side effects?
Can you assume that no additional memory is allocated?
Would anything go against such an idea?

Comment: No, you cannot assume that an object's initializer allocates no memory. Why would you want to in the first place?

Comment: I used the IB to create an object and link it with the corresponding controller outlet. I observed that this object is initialized, so assumed that +alloc and -init must have been called. So the question came up, if i could init the object again with different values.

Comment: If you have instantiated an object in Interface Builder, you need to override `-initWithCoder:` as that will be called instead of `-init`, since the object is archived in the nib and must be unarchived to be available to the app. Alternatively, just implement `-awakeFromNib` and change whatever settings you want at that point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Calling `-init` multiple times is undefined, unsupported, and **will** lead to bugs, crashes, and other unexpected behavior.

Many classes -- `NSString`, `NSArray`, and `NSDictionary`, for example -- don't actually allocate *anything* when the `+alloc` method is called.  It isn't until one of the various `-init*` methods are called that the object has enough context to figure out the most efficient means of doing whatever you ask.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I'd add to Bill's answer is that when writing your own `-init` methods, code defensively and don't assume that they'll only be invoked once.

Comment: how do you go about checking elegantly that no init method has been called on the object?