# NSXMLParser replaces é characters with \U00e9

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I'm using an xml parser, `NSXMLParser` to parse asn xml an return some `url` in an  `NSMutableArray`.Everything is giong great except the fact that the `french é` is replaced by `\U00e9`.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    xmlParser = [NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [xmlParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [xmlParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [xmlParser parse];
}



- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{       

    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"catalogue"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        currentCatalogue = [[Catalogue alloc] init];
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"partenaire"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        currentPartenaire = [[Partenaire alloc] init];
    }
}

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"catalogue"]) {       
            // Add currentCatalogue to array
            [catalogueList addObject: currentCatalogue];
            NSString *urls=[catalogueList valueForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"Current catalogue: urls=%@", urls);
        }

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"partenaire"]) {      
            // Add currentPartenaire to array
            [partenaireList addObject: currentPartenaire];
            /*NSLog(@"Current partenaire: raison_sociale=%@, lat=%@, lng=%@", currentPartenaire.raison_sociale, currentPartenaire.lat, currentPartenaire.lng);*/
        }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        // Catalogue setup
        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"id_model"])
            currentCatalogue.id_model = string;

        if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"url"])
        {
            if (currentCatalogue.url)
            {
                currentCatalogue.url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", currentCatalogue.url, string];

             //   NSLog(@"Valoare url in data handler %@", currentCatalogue.url);
            }
            else
                currentCatalogue.url = string;


        }
    }
```

Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to parse here: You initialize xmlParser with a strong containing an XML fragment, and then you appear to re-initialize the same parser using the contents of a URL. Are you seeing the problem when you parse the content of the URL, the XML fragment string, or both?

Comment: What I want is my parser to retun french e when it meets french e and not return its ascii code instead.If you know how to do it, please help me.I'm a beginner so I can't explain too much.Thank you:)

Comment: And you appear to be calling two different init methods on a single NSXMLParser object (once when allocated, and another when you assign to parser). This is a bad thing to do (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989532/calling-init-multiple-times-in-objective-c/1989562#1989562).

Comment: You need to first look at how the french e gets put into the XML file - In other words, how is it encoded in the file. Once you know how it is encoded in the file that will inform how you retrieve and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED CODE : 100 % WORKS**

```
NSString* inputString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\40_TTRS_Coup\u00e9_TTRS_Roadster_Tarifs_20110428.pdf"];


NSLog(@"inputString is: %@ \n\n",inputString);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  inputString is:  _TTRS_Coupé_TTRS_Roadster_Tarifs_20110428.pdf
```

Comment: as far as I know UTF8 is the default coding for NSXMLParser!

Comment: And where is the code that does that? this NSString* inputString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\40_TTRS_Coup\u00e9_TTRS_Roadster_Tarifs_20110428.pdf"];  ?

Comment: When you use it like this  NSString *inputString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,urls];
 NSLog(@"After catalogue: urls=%@", inputString);  is not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your XML has an explicit encoding, as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

then there are 2 problems you should address first. These may or may not fix your direct problem, but if not they will make it easier to narrow in on the problem you are seeing. Here are the problems you should fix:

1. Remove the code that calls 2 different initializer methods on a single NSXMLParser instance. That will have undefined results and its impossible to know what is going on until you fix that.
2. Change how you implement the parser:foundCharacters: method. As NSXMLParser documentations states, this may be called multiple times for a given set of characters within an XML element. Instead of just accepting the string and storing its value away, your delegate class should have a mutable character buffer that you append to each time foundCharacters gets called. Then in parser:didElementEnd you can grab the contents of the buffer and do what you need to with that value.

Try it out with these fixes and see if it works. If not, update your post with a corrected version of your code and it might be more obvious what the problem is.

Comment: My xml has this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ?>

Comment: Updated my response based on your clarification that this is clearly UTF8-encoded XML