# fatal error: method declaration not in @interface context

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What does this error mean ? Following is my code. But I don't see anything wrong

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Player.png" 
                                               rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)];
        player.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:player];     
    }

    if( (self=[super initWithColor:ccc4(255,255,255,255)] )) 
    {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You should never be setting `self` twice let alone [calling `init` twice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1989562/418715). If you have done this anywhere else in your code you need to undo it and reconsider your logic.

Comment: I agree with Joe above. Also what line gives you the error?

Comment: Learning to format your code properly will help a lot.

Comment: I do not see the point in calling two different super init... methods. Do you realize that "self=..." is an assignment and not a comparison as in other languages?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error if you write a property or method declaration outside of the  @interface … @end block, specifically if you place it either before @interface or after @end. Here's an example that would cause this error:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    // instance vars here
}

// properties and method declarations here

@end

// ERROR: method declared outside @interface (after @end)
-(void) someMethodWithObject:(id)obj;
```